# cakephp websocket ratchet install error

Tags: cakephp, ratchet

I am trying to install [Cakephp Ratchet Plugin](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/Ratchet)  in existing project.
My CakePHP version is 2.4.3.
It says to follow [this link](http://ceeram.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/using-composer-with-cakephp-2-dot-x/)  which has following steps:

```
 $ cd myproject/app/
 $ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
 $ php composer.phar require --no-update opauth/opauth:dev-wip/1.0 opauth/twitter:dev-     wip/1.0
 $ php composer.phar config vendor-dir Vendor
 $ php composer.phar install
```

I am not very familiar with composer and when i do the last step,it shows following error....

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package opauth/opauth could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 2
- The requested package opauth/twitter could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
```

EDIT:
Composer.json is like this

```
    {
"require": {
"opauth/opauth": "dev-wip/1.0",
    "opauth/twitter": "dev-wip/1.0"
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
}
  }
```

Comment: As far as I understand the docs are just referring to the composer and bootstrap configuration, not to these opauth packages! Do you have a `composer.json` file for your project? If so, what does it look like and where exactly is it placed? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: I have edited and added composer.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment, the Ratchet Plugin has nothing to do with [Opauth](http://opauth.org/), the linked article over at `ceeram.github.io` should only serve as an example on how to configure Composer and the CakePHP bootstrap.

However, for Composer autoloading in CakePHP I'd recommend to refer to the CakePHP cookbook, even if you're not including CakePHP itself via Composer:

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html**

Long story short, what the "***Getting Started / 2. Composer***" section of the plugin docs want you to do, is to require the ratchet plugin, to make sure the vendor dir points to `/app/Vendor/`, and to include the Composer autoloader in your `bootstrap.php`.

**composer.json** (assuming it's placed in `/app`)

```
{
    "require": {
        "wyrihaximus/ratchet": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.php** (as per Cookbook)

```
// Load Composer autoload.
require APP . '/Vendor/autoload.php';

// Remove and re-prepend CakePHP's autoloader as Composer thinks it is the
// most important.
// See: http://goo.gl/kKVJO7
spl_autoload_unregister(array('App', 'load'));
spl_autoload_register(array('App', 'load'), true, true);
```

Run `composer install` or `composer update` and you should be good.

Comment: i was able to do that... could you explain me next step too... setting up ratchet and asssetcompress...Thank You..

Comment: I added "CakePlugin::load('Ratchet',array('bootstrap' => true));" in bootstrap.php and did ">cd {Your Cake Project}/app/Console/
    > chmod +x cake
    > ./cake Ratchet.websocket start"
but it shows:
 Your configuration doesn't seem to support 'ext-libevent'. It is highly reccomended that you install and configure it as it provides significant performance gains over stream select!

Comment: @Nemesis AFAICT that's a warning, not an error. [**`ext-libevent`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.libevent.php) is an optional extension suggested by [**`reactphp/event-loop`**](https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop/blob/v0.4.0/composer.json). However, I'm not familiar with ratchet or reactphp, so I can't really give any solid advice other than to make yourself acquainted with how these libraries work.